# Is there a way to create a class that holds just class name in string rather just doing it manually in Java?

Tags: java, class

I need to create a bunch of classes in Java 8 that hold just one field ‘name’, that holds name of the class. Is there a way to do it faster then just writing all by hands?

Comment: can't it be done by enum?

Comment: Why do you want to create these classes? I glimpse into the context might help to answer your question better.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Need more context.

Comment: The only use for the string is to name the class, and the only use for the class is to provide the string. Seems completely pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name of the java class can be obtained for any class by something like below. this prints just the className

```
    public class ClassNameExample {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ClassNameExample classExample= new ClassNameExample();
            System.out.println(classExample.getClass().getSimpleName());//using instance
            System.out.println(ClassNameExample.class.getSimpleName());//using class

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write a script, man:

```
public class ClassGenerator {

// Edit your package name
private static final String packageName = "com.thanh";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("classes.txt"))));

    String clazz = null;

    while ((clazz = reader.readLine()) != null){
        generateFileForClass(clazz);
    }

}

private static void generateFileForClass(String clazz) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("package ").append(packageName).append(";\n\n");
    sb.append("public class ").append(clazz).append(" {\n");

    // You may mark this field private and generate getter & setter also

    sb.append("    public String clazzName = ").append("\"")
            .append(packageName).append(".").append(clazz).append("\";\n");
    sb.append("}");

    writeToFile(clazz, sb);
}

private static void writeToFile(String clazzName, StringBuffer fileContent) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(clazzName+".java"))));
    writer.write(fileContent.toString());
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
}
```

The above program will read from a `classes.txt` file and generate Java files to current directory.

`classes.txt` looks like this:

```
Hello
Hi
Foo
Bar
```

Each class name on a line.

You can then move generated files to the desired folder to match package name.